# Kubuntu 14.04 doesn't detect dGPU NVIDIA GeForce 740M

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, kubuntu

I have Lenovo IdeaPad Z500 laptop and fresh Kubuntu 14.04 installed on it with Windows 8.1. I have a problem: Kubuntu doesn't detect my dGPU NVIDIA GeForce 740M. Example:

```
piotr@piotr-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)                                                                                  
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)                                                             
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)                                                                
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)                                                         
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)                                                      
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)                                                  
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)                                                   
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)                                                              
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)                                                              
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)                                                  
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)                                                                                      
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)                                                          
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)                                                                          
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
```

A also purged all packages associated with NVIDIA. I have to say that after Kubuntu installation it have seen it, but few days after this issue have appeared.

PS Sorry for my English. If something you can't understand, I can rewrite it. :)

Comment: How do you know you have an Nvidia adapter?

Comment: I know I have NVIDIA GeForce GPU, because under Windows 8.1 everything works fine. For example if I run xcom: enemy unknown I can play at highest details.

Comment: Do you really see the Nvidia adapter in Windows Device manager?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that under Windows 8.1 x64 everything works fine and NVIDIA adapter is in Windows Device manager.

Comment: @Pysiek please try out my answer and post back whether it works. :)

Comment: @Pysiek Did you ever have bumblebee installed ?

Comment: Yes, because I have tried many tips from the Internet until I posted here.

Answer (score 1):

Your **lspci output** shows that you **currently** are using the **integrated intel graphics solution**.

Install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers supporting GT 740 from the Proprietary GPU drivers PPA.

Before you install new drivers uninstall every NVIDIA related software you have installed before.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge '^nvidia.*'  
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee
sudo reboot
```

Then install the latest current stable NVIDIA drivers from the long-lived branch by executing :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 
sudo reboot
```

In case you are using a notebook with a hybrid graphics solution install Optimus support as well.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```

To switch between intel and nvidia graphics - open **NVIDIA X Server Settings** -> **Prime Profiles**.

After switching to **NVIDIA** run **sudo lspci** again and the output shows your **NVIDIA GT 740 GPU**.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30323/discussion-on-answer-by-cl-netbox-kubuntu-14-04-doesnt-detect-dgpu-nvidia-gefor).